# What is the correct certificate to setup for AppleScript apps?

Tags: applescript, catalina, mac-appstore, code-signing

In the past I haven't been code signing but with the new security features that are in current operating systems I thought I should to prevent user issues.

Under [Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/add) my understanding if I want to sell an app on the app store I should use:

> **Mac Installer Distribution** This certificate is used to sign your app's Installer Package for submission to the Mac App Store.

If I want to sell an app or script on a website outside of the app store I should use:

> **Developer ID Application** This certificate is used to code sign your app for distribution outside of the Mac App Store.

For clarity I'm trying to learn how to add the signage for when I export an application from **Script Editor** and I want to be able to add the **Code Sign** that would be placed in the dropdown.

When I try to research for this Im not having any luck from Google or the docs. What is the correct procedure for code signing an AppleScript app that I intend to push to the app store?

Comment: RE: "For clarity I'm trying to learn how to add the signage for when I export an application from **Script Editor**" --  Is the exported _application_ just for your own usage or are you going to distribute the _application_? If/when you have a _certificate_ it should be in your **Keychain** and will be available to select from in the **Code Sign:** _pop up_. If it's just for your own usage, have a look at: [Create self-signed certificates in Keychain Access on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/create-self-signed-certificates-kyca8916/mac)

Comment: @user3439894 how is that different than creating one for an org per the linked certificates in the question?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't follow the link in your question because I didn't what to have to sign-in at that moment so I just offered something I'd seen before. That said, and having finished reading your question it's probably moot as you want to distribute thru the **Mac App Store**, ("that I intend to push to the app store"), and as such it would appear you need to have a **Mac Installer Distribution** _ certificate_ based on what you quoted in your question.